# Pricing discount logic, 2 for $4, 6 for the price of 5

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, object, modulus

So i'm currently working on some pricing logic where the situations are:

- 1 glove costs $2.50, 2 gloves costs $4, therefore applying a 20% discount.
- If person buys 3 gloves then it should be the $4 + original price of $2.50 making total $6.50
- If person buys 4 gloves then it should be $8.

---

- 1 gum costs $0.65, you can buy 6 for the price of 5, so $3.25 for 6 instead of $3.90
- If person buys 7, then it should be 6 for $3.25 + original price of $0.65 totalling $3.90
- If person buys 8, then it should be 6 for $3.25 + (original price of $0.65 * 2) totalling $4.55

So it's very important at what index/stage that the discount needs to be applied by

I took my logic inspiration from this article:
http://codekata.com/kata/kata01-supermarket-pricing/

I took my code inspiration from this article:
https://github.com/raddanesh/Kata01

Specifically the VolumePricingStrategy as show in this diagram:[image]

Here is my code attempt given the logic i want to achieve:

```
//2 for $4
const gloves = {quantity: 3, price: 2.50 }

function volumePriceGloves(threshold = 2){
  let regularPrice = gloves.quantity * gloves.price;
  let volumeDiscount = 0;
    
  let volumePrice = regularPrice * 0.8;

  if(gloves.quantity >= threshold){
    volumeDiscount = threshold * gloves.price - volumePrice
  }
  return regularPrice - volumeDiscount;
}

// 5 for the price of 6
const gum = {quantity: 7, price: 0.65 }

function volumePriceGum(threshold = 6){
  let regularPrice = gum.quantity * gum.price;
  let volumeDiscount = 0;
  
  let volumePrice = regularPrice * 0.16666667;

  if(gum.quantity % threshold){
    volumeDiscount = threshold * gum.price - volumePrice;
  }
  
  return regularPrice - volumeDiscount; 
}
```

My code is obviously wrong because it outputs the incorrect values when calling the functions. Although I very much like the code written by github.com/raddanesh/Kata01 and can understand the concepts behind it. I'm really struggling to truly understand what volumePrice is representing. In my mind the volumePrice is what the discounted price of that product is given that they meet the threshold.

So for the gloves scenario it makes sense for volumePrice to be regularPrice * 0.8 which represents a 20% discount of the original price. However my intentions don't quite formulate in my code volumePriceGloves(3) returns 6 instead of 6.5 and all the scenarios don't match if you change the threshold parameter amount. Any ideas/help is much appreciated!

For the gum scenario, i'm not quite sure if the code example by github.com/raddanesh/Kata01 can be applied to this logic. As it seems quite different and i'm not sure what approach to really take.
As you can see i've made volumePrice on this one regularPrice * 0.16666667, which reflects the discount amount per gum.

Another idea i thought of was potentially putting the prices into an array and popping the last one out given it meets the threshold however i'm not sure how feasible that is i still need that item in the array for further calculations. This one i think is the trickiest and i couldn't find many good examples online, hence this post! All ideas/suggestions are welcome!

Comment: `I'm really struggling to truly understand what volumePrice is representing` -- A volume price is simply a discount given when someone orders a certain number of products.  For example, if you order 1 pencil, the cost for each pencil is $1.  If you order two pencils, the cost for each pencil is $0.90, for a total cost of $9 instead of $10.  If you order 100 pencils, the cost of each is $0.80 for a total cost of $80, not $90 or $100.

Comment: In short, I think you may be overthinking this.  If this is a homework problem, ask for sample input and output.  That should clarify some of your concerns.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ermm ok. That kinda makes sense but couldn't I customize the volumePrice in the way i want to(which is what i think i'm doing above). The example you just mentioned above is arbitrary right?  You're probably right that i'm overthinking

Comment: Yes, my example is an arbitrary one.  The volume discount brackets can be stored any way you want: directly in code, in a dictionary, in a database, in a JSON file, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both situations require pretty much the same logic -- there's an individual price, and a group price, and any item that doesn't fit in a group gets the individual price.

So my approach would be to just use that as the basis for the logic. Write a function that takes as an input the qty, the group-qty, the individual price and the group price, like so:

```js
function getPrice(qty, groupQty, indivPrice, groupPrice) {
  const groupCount = Math.floor(qty / groupQty);
  const indivCount = qty % groupQty;
  return (groupCount * groupPrice) + (indivCount * indivPrice);
}

console.log(getPrice(5, 2, 1.5, 2.5)); // groups of 2 cost 2.5, but 1 costs 1.5 -- total should be 6.5
```

So from this point on, all you would need to do is figure out the 'groupPrice' depending on what type of deal it is

Comment: thanks, this is definitely a good foundation for me start on. I will give you the green tick answer as soon i've got it to work for my situation!

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of ways to do this. I tend to go the route of less code.

I would go this route.

```
if(quantity => threshold){

discounteditems = Math.floor(quantity/threhold);
remainder = quantity%threhold;
discountedtotalprice = discounteditems * discountedprice;
fullprice = remainder * fullprice;
```

}

This way you get all your discounted items, what is outside this threshold you charge the full price.

For me, this is a lot simpler method of getting the desire you are looking for.

Comment: interesting! Just like yourself i also like less code. I'll let you know how my integration of your suggestions goes shortly.

Comment: TKoL got there before I did =)... I need to type faster lol. The same concept - just use Math.floor and Modulus (%). I would go with his code - it's more drop-in ready.

Comment: hehe thanks, i'll give you the "this answer is useful" because it is.  I'll let uno if i implement yours or TkoL's.